# Why do I get errors in importing components in this way? am I missing something in the code?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I created a vue with vuetify feature project and I'm getting these errors.
[first past of errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBNwo.png)

[Second block of errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HECfQ.png)

This is how I structure the project.

[Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOYjX.png)

This is the code for VideoPrueba.vue

```html
<template>
<div>
     <v-row>
                  <v-col
                    class="d-flex justify-center"
                    cols="6"
                  >
                    <div class="positionButton">
                      <v-btn
                        class="accent-3 blue"
                        dark
                      >
                        Add voice
                      </v-btn>
                    </div>
                  </v-col>
                  <v-col
                    class="d-flex justify-center"
                    cols="6"
                  >
                    <VideoPrueba
                      v-for="(step, key) in steps"
                      :key="key"
                      v-model="step.selected"
                      :items="step.options"
                    />
                  </v-col>
                </v-row>
                </div>
</template>

<script>
import VideoPrueba from './VideoPrueba'
  export default {
    name: 'HelloWorld',
    components:'VideoPrueba',
   
    data: () => ({
       steps: [
      {
        title: 'Videos',
        options: ['Video 1', 'Video 2', 'Video 3', 'Video 4'],
        selected: []
      }
    ],
   } )
  }
</script>
```

This is the code for HelloWorld.vue

```html
<template>
<div>
     <v-row>
                  <v-col
                    class="d-flex justify-center"
                    cols="6"
                  >
                    <div class="positionButton">
                      <v-btn
                        class="accent-3 blue"
                        dark
                      >
                        Add voice
                      </v-btn>
                    </div>
                  </v-col>
                  <v-col
                    class="d-flex justify-center"
                    cols="6"
                  >
                    <VideoPrueba
                      v-for="(step, key) in steps"
                      :key="key"
                      v-model="step.selected"
                      :items="step.options"
                    />
                  </v-col>
                </v-row>
                </div>
</template>

<script>
import VideoPrueba from './VideoPrueba'
  export default {
    name: 'HelloWorld',
    components:'VideoPrueba',
   
    data: () => ({
       steps: [
      {
        title: 'Videos',
        options: ['Video 1', 'Video 2', 'Video 3', 'Video 4'],
        selected: []
      }
    ],
   } )
  }
</script>
```

This is for App.vue

```html
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-app-bar
      app
      color="primary"
      dark
    >
      <div class="d-flex align-center">
        <v-img
          alt="Vuetify Logo"
          class="shrink mr-2"
          contain
          src="https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/logos/vuetify-logo-dark.png"
          transition="scale-transition"
          width="40"
        />

        <v-img
          alt="Vuetify Name"
          class="shrink mt-1 hidden-sm-and-down"
          contain
          min-width="100"
          src="https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/logos/vuetify-name-dark.png"
          width="100"
        />
      </div>

      <v-spacer></v-spacer>

      <v-btn
        href="https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/releases/latest"
        target="_blank"
        text
      >
        <span class="mr-2">Latest Release</span>
        <v-icon>mdi-open-in-new</v-icon>
      </v-btn>
    </v-app-bar>

    <v-main>
      <HelloWorld/>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld';

export default {
  name: 'App',

  components: {
    HelloWorld,
  },

  data: () => ({
    //
  }),
};
</script>
```

And this is what I have for main.js

```html
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'
import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify';

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  vuetify,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

Any idea, thanks ?

Comment: `components:'VideoPrueba',` etc should be `components: {VideoPrueba},`

Comment: Thanks a lot ,It worked.